# Как правильно создавать и использовать стрелочные функции

Tags: javascript

```
const b = aa();

const aa = () => {
    return 'aa';
}
```

тут мне ругается что он не инициализирован. я это понимаю, но я написал вчера точно так стрелочную функцию и это работало. В чем подвох? не могу понять.

https://github.com/diasgalymbek47/Shop/blob/main/script.js <-- вот код, который я написал.

Comment: Вы присваиваете стрелочную функцию переменной, а javaScript инициализирует переменные последовательно. Поменяйте объявление переменных местами и все заработает

Comment: Нет, вчера была не точно такая же. Вчера вызов этой функции был внутри обработчика события.

Comment: @AlexeyTen думал что они как обычные функции в конце можно написать, а нет оказывается. Теперь буду использовать обычную

Comment: стрелочные функции не поднимаются, т.е. вызвать их до объявления нельзя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У стрелочной функции нет имени, их надо присваивать переменной чтобы вызывать. Поэтому их надо вызывать после присвоения переменной.